# How to check if a value is a puppeteer browser?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

As stated in the title, I would like to know if it possible to check if a value is a puppeteer browser.

Edit : I want this to happen at runtime via `instanceof`. I do not want to have to launch an extra browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's many methods to detect headless chrome and puppeteer by extension.

https://antoinevastel.com/bot%20detection/2018/01/17/detect-chrome-headless-v2.html

Take a look at this article for a writeup on some older, and newer methods. There are also plenty of private, non-disclosed methods companies are using with many more being found all the time.

On the other side of the playing field, there is a library that attempts to defeat the detection processes.

https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

It's honestly a huge game of cat and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just leaving a second answer in case your question asking something different.

If you are asking how, in code, do you assert that a certain variable is of the puppeteer browser type then this answer applies.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/puppeteer

You'll want to use this in conjunction with Typescript to correctly check for the type of a variable being passed as being a puppeteer instance.

Comment: I am not looking for static type checking . I am looking for checking via `instanceof` in runtime . And that check I would like it to be without me having to launch a browser.

Comment: @Jordan, you should first use the comments to clarify what question author means before answering with guesses (good answers, btw). Currently the question needs to be updated with more details.

Comment: Only just unlocked comments significantly after posting this :) thank you though @Vaviloff